# Unable to connect kubernetes cluster to azure using arc enabled kubernetes cluster for checking the workloads and monitoring the clusters

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-aks, kubernetes-pod

I am trying to create a protected kubernetes cluster on azure for that I have created the resource group name exampe1,after that created the arc enabled kubernetes cluster for the same resource group
I have followed [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-arc/kubernetes/extensions) added the some extensions and connected to the cluster using the command

```
az connectedk8s connect --name cluster123 --resource-group rgexample --location eastus
```

so that the cluster got connected successfully to the azure

After that I want to see the workloads which are running on my kubernetes cluster and I want to monitor the
clusters which are there on my cluster

I have given some access token to connect the workload but I am not able to see any workloads and monitoring cluster which are running on my cluster

[reference image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/59r5q.png)

Can any one help me that how to connect and what is the issue will be much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***I tried to reproduce the same issue in my environment and got the below results***

***I have created the resource group and arc enabled kubernetes cluster***

***While creating cluster I have added k8s extensions using below commands***

```
az login
az extension add --name connectedk8s
az extension add --name k8s-extension
az extension add --name customlocation
az provider register --namespace microsoft.kubernetesConfiguration
az provider show -n Microsoft.kubernetesConfiguration --query "registrationState"

az account set --subscription sub_id
az connectedk8s connect --name <cluster-name> --resource-group <rg-name> --location eastus --correlation-id <c-id>
```

***Created the arc enabled kubernetes cluster successfully and connected to azure***

[image]

***When I check in workloads I didn't find any nodes or pods, for that I have added the "service account bearer token"***

```
kubectl create serviceaccount admin-user
kubectl create clusterrolebinding admin-user-binding --cluster-role cluster-admin --serviceaccount default:admin-user
$SECRET-NAME=kubectl get serviceaccount admin-user -o jsonpath='{$.secrets[0].name}'
$BASE64=kubectl get secret $SECRET_name -o jsonpath='{$.data.token}' [Text.Encoding]::Utf8.GetString([Convert]::FromBase64String($BASE64))
<!-- | base64 -d |sed $'s/$/\\n/g') -->
```

***By Running the above command one token will be generated Using those token I can be able to see the workloads***

[image]

***We can check all the pods ,namespaces and nodes which we have created in the workloads
For monitoring the pods/nodes etc. click on insights and click on configure azure  monitor it will onboarded***

[image]

***Here we can monitor all the pods and nodes information with the their CPU while clicking on reports***

[image]